# Internet Explorer CPU usage goes high after an animated GIF image has been displayed

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have been working on a web application for some time now and did notice that the CPU usage was a bit high a long time ago, but the development has been halted for a while.

Recently I started developing again and discovered that the CPU usage goes high after an animated GIF image has been display as the background image.

I use Ajax to update content and apply CSS classes to elements to display a loading indicator. I remove the CSS class when the content has finished loading. If I comment out the classes in the stylesheet that contains the GIFs, everything looks normal.

I have tested it in Internet Explorer 7 and Internet Explorer 8.

What can be done to alliviate this problem?

```
var blabla = function() {
    var element = $('id of element');
    element.addClassName('a css classname');

    new Ajax.Request({some parameters},
        onSuccess: function() {
            element.removeClassName('a CSS classname');
            ....
        },
        onFailure: function() {
            element.removeClassName('a CSS classname');
            ....
        },
        onComplete: function() {
            element.removeClassName('a CSS classname');
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, animations will inevitably take up CPU cycles. Just how high is the usage, and how powerful is the computer?

Comment: You've posted no code or described anything meaningful about the animation, although I can understand an animated background causing high CPU usage depending on the PC.  Presumably, the entire window must redraw itself many times in succession.

Comment: I'm talking about after the animation has been removed. Tiny image ~20x20px. CPU is about 20%. Same on different computers. The code is nothing more than $('id').addClassName('loading_indicator'); and $('id').removeClassName('loading_indicator'); I'm using prototype.

Comment: This is only a guess:  No matter how small the animation, if it's set as the entire background, the entire window must redraw itself despite how inefficient it seems.  If it's nothing to do with the animated background, then your question is misleading and incomplete.  Perhaps post all the relevant code along with a link to the page so people can actually do something here.

Comment: Must the window redraw itself when the image has been removed also?

Comment: How do I know why/when CPU usage is going up when I can't see your page?  I'm only taking your word that the animation is causing it and offering possible reasons.

Comment: Its an intranet page. I have tried it with different animations

Comment: So it's an intranet page... why can't you copy the code to a page online or to a JSFiddle?

Comment: Hey, doc, it hurts *when I do this...*

Comment: fwiw, this is a bug in IE, but where I put my note on that, I don't know, so I can't leave this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that this issue is related to how Internet Explorer loads data needed from CSS classes. Might I suggest an alternate approach: instead of using the loading animation contained within a CSS class, just put the .gif in a visible `<img>` tag straight into the HTML. Then, when `onSuccess` or another method is called, you can just run:

```
$("#ajax-gif").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

As already commented on, it looks like it doesn't have anything to do with the GIF image itself, especially not one at 20x20 pixels.

If you are changing the background of a page with a GIF image, it must redraw what's on top of it to a certain extent.

To bring down the CPU usage, either reduce what's on your page before you change the background or stop using GIF images, it's 2011!

Comment: Just curious: what would be the alternatives to gif?

Comment: @Vercas -- Good to know -- never tried it. APNG looks like it is only supported by GIMP via plugin, but probably no big deal -- I was honestly afraid that you were suggesting Flash -- Do you know if APNG is supported on mobile devices (iPhone/Pad, Android)?

Comment: @Vercas -- Looking at Wikipedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG#Application_support Safari and IE does not look like they are supporting APNG, nor does Chrome out-of-the-box -- so given "it has always worked for you" does that mean you are only developing for Firefox, or is the table in wikipedia outdated?

Answer (score 0):

If this problem is only occurring in Internet Explorer, it is indeed the redraw issue that commenters to [Barnzy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710783/internet-explorer-cpu-usage-goes-high-after-an-animated-gif-image-has-been-displa/6762909#6762909) have talked about. It should create similar problems across other browsers as well.

One solution would be to use the JavaScript `onload` event handler to preload all of your GIF images in the DOM, which would reduce the need to redraw and should stop escalating the CPU cycles.

I agree that in 2011 using GIF images is probably not the best approach for web design.